# How do I merge multiple objects so I can sculpt it?

Tags: sculpting

[image: so **strong text**]

As the title implies, how do I do this? Is there maybe an add-on to make it easier? I did ctrl-J to join all the bodies together, but they really weren't connected as one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Search in the add-ons window "bool tool".
2. Select the two mesh that your want to join.
3. Go to the object menu in the view-port,bool tool operation, and select "union".
4. And wuala! you have a unified object.

You can do this without the add-on using only modifiers but its a little bit wonky 
Hope it helps!

[image: two meshes joined]

Comment: thank you so much, i've been trying to figure this out all day lmfao